# How do I implement a timer into my elevator to delay the changing of floor?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

When a floor button is pressed by a person inside the lift, it calls the method ChangeFloor to inc/decrease the chosen lift's level. Two parameters are passed to the ChangeFloor function; the lift's label(floor indicator) and the button pressed to gain the floor they're on through btn.Name. Tried implementing a timer but can't seem to get it to start? 'timer1' created through the toolbar.

```
private void FloorButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        if (Convert.ToInt16(btn.Name) > 40)
            if (Convert.ToInt16(btn.Name) > 80)
                if (Convert.ToInt16(btn.Name) > 120)
                    ChangeFloor(lblLiftFloor4, btn);
                else
                    ChangeFloor(lblLiftFloor3, btn);
            else
                ChangeFloor(lblLiftFloor2, btn);
        else
            ChangeFloor(lblLiftFloor1, btn);
    }

 private void ChangeFloor(Label lift, Button btn)
    {
        int level = Convert.ToInt16(lift.Text);
        int desired = Convert.ToInt16(btn.Tag);

        while( level!=desired )
        {
            if (level > desired)
            {
                timer1.Start();
                lift.Text = (--level).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Start();
                lift.Text = (++level).ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any code handling the Timer's `Elapsed` event? For reference, the [Timer Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). `timer1.Start()` simply starts raising the elapsed event, you still need to handle it.

Comment: I attempted that by adding an ElapsedEventHandler but then I'd want to link it to ChangeFloor(Label, Button) but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly... if you just want to simulate the changing of floors and introduce a delay, you could just throw in a `Sleep` statement which will cause your app to pause for a given amount of time.

```
private void ChangeFloor(Label lift, Button btn)
{
    int level = Convert.ToInt16(lift.Text);
    int desired = Convert.ToInt16(btn.Tag);

    while( level!=desired )
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);  // <--- Pause for 3 seconds...
        if (level > desired)
        {
            lift.Text = (--level).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lift.Text = (++level).ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT:  Read up of threading because if you want a bunch of independent elevators. Threads are what you could implement to achieve the behavior you're looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, ill try to clarify. I have 4 lifts that should be in use independently of one another, wouldn't this cause them to become static while the thread sleeps when it should only be the one lift? Wanted to incorporate a timer into it so that it does exactly this but pauses only the one. EDIT: Also noticed that this seems to pause the thread and then jump from say floor 30 to 17 straight off, instead of gradually doing so.

Comment: @matt9251 Well depending how you implement the elevators themselves.  If each one is running in their own thread then doing  a sleep should only affect the current thread.  Not sure how you have the rest implemented.  Just put a break point in it and you can see what is going on as it should not be 'jumping' unless it's a UI issue.

Comment: they are all within the same thread currently unfortunately. I stepped through it and it does the inc/decrement of the floor but seems to fail to output it visually to the form which makes me believe that its not changing the number until it completes the entire function